# BCP Command to Export Query Results to File with Pipe Delimiter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I have a requirement to create a SQL Job that exports a query to a Pipe / Vertical bar delimited file (|) and save it on a network drive in either *.txt or *.csv format.  Right now, I am just trying to get this to work inside SSMS, calling the BCP command and exporting the stored procedure in the proper format to the network location, but not able to get it working.

I have been researching this and there are two methods for this.

Use the export data wizard to create a job and schedule that to run.  But this method, if we need to make changes, I believe we cannot change the SSIS package that is created so we lose flexibility
Use the BCP command to export the file.
I greatly prefer to use option #2, the BCP command, but I am having problems.  I just cannot seem to get the syntax correct and hoping someone could show me what I am missing:

This is my command:

```
Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp EXEC [dbo].[usp_Report_1123] ''7786'' -t| out \\networkDrive\Reports\REPORT_1123\report1123.csv -T'
```

But I get the following messages:

output

'out' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

NULL

The stored procedure does work and returns data. The network path, if I enter it into my computer, finds the path.  But I am not sure what I am missing and hoping someone could help.

Comment: You should be able to use SSIS to do what you want.  You can create one from the automated tool like you mentioned, then save it, and go in and update/edit it to be more dynamic to account for what you want.  For your error, your network path starts with \  your missing something in the path it looks like or your path from local has access but the server does not

Comment: Please note: BCP is not csv aware. You may need to add quotes on text columns

Comment: In cmd shells the `|` pipe character is used to connect processes via their stdout/stdin streams. You're going to have to escape it.